# How do I not start sinatra when Gemfile refers to it?

Tags: sinatra

all, I have a client application which is a sinatra app, but that's only part of it, some other parts will do related work like download so need to spawn in a new process, this is  mostly required the gem dependencies of the same client project, so I of course using some code to load in the bundler environment:

```
Dir.chdir(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.expand_path("../Gemfile", __FILE__)
require 'bundler'
env = ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
Bundler.setup
Bundler.require :default, env.to_sym,
```

but unfornately even with no code,like
puts 3,the sinatra app will starts and listens on 4567 which is quite irritating,
I also tried modular approach to write in the file an empty class

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base;
end
```

but still sinatra starts on 4567, which is 
quite irritating, 
do I have a way not to start sinatra? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the problem,
because in Gemfile, is:
gem "sinatra",
better use
gem "sinatra", :require =>"sinatra/base"
instead.